# Displaying entries from category groups

Tags: templates, categories

Excuse my template tagging if is looks confusing. I am fairly new to ExpressionEngine and using categories is my latest adventure.

On this following page [Click here](http://bodyworksforme.com/?/blog/full-post/sport-feature) under the "more sport" section of this page I want to display a max of 4 of the most recent post within it's category, I need to do the same for the other five category.

I have made attempts to this section but it seems to duplicate the same entry post 4 times rather than four different post within the category. This is also happening on my blog roll page [Click here](http://bodyworksforme.com/?/blog/blog-roll/category/wellness)

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

```
      <ul class="post">
   {exp:channel:entries dynamic="yes" sort="asc" status="open" limit="4"}

        {categories}
        <li>
        <a href="{url_title_path='blog/full-post'}">
        <a href="{path='blog/blog-roll'}">
            <div class="featured-tab {url_title}"></div>
        </a>
            <a href="{url_title_path='blog/full-post'}"><img src="{blog_slide_image}" alt="placeholder" class="feature-preview-img"></a>
                <p>{exp:eehive_hacksaw chars="250" append="..."}{feature_copy}{/exp:eehive_hacksaw}</p>
</li>
    {/categories}

    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Code for blog roll

```
<ul class="results-row">
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" disable="member_data|trackbacks" dynamic="yes"}
{exp:channel:categories channel="blog" style="linear" show_empty="no" }
        <li>
        <a href="{url_title_path='blog/full-post'}">
            <div class="featured-tab {url_title}"></div>
            <img src="{blog_slide_image}" alt="placeholder" class="feature-preview-img"></a>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            <p>{exp:eehive_hacksaw chars="150" append="..."}{feature_copy}{/exp:eehive_hacksaw}</p>
        </li>
        {/exp:channel:categories}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
        </ul><!-- RESULTS-ROW ENDS HERE-->
```

Answer (score 5):

Good morning!

Let's step back for a moment. First, if you are new to EE and especially categories then I'd recommend reading through [this tutorial I wrote a while back.](http://www.train-ee.com/courseware/free-tutorials/comments/working-with-categories)

Basically I think you are trying too hard, and shouldn't need to nest entries tags into category tags like that - it not only shouldn't be necessary but can be a performance drain as well.

On the first question if you are looking to display other entries in the same category as the entry being displayed then look at the [related categories mode parameter](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#related-categories-mode) for the channel entries tag.

If instead it's just a category page showing the most recent 4 entries in a category (and isn't showing an entire single entry) then all you'll need is the template loaded at a category URL with the channel:entries tag and a limit parameter set to 4 (and the tutorial I linked to above would demonstrate this).

I'm not sure what you mean by "tagging" - in EE-land tags are different from categories and require a 3rd party add-on to implement.

Comment: Love your work @Michael - always a lifesaver!!!

Answer (score 2):

As Michael stated in his answer, you will need to use [**Related Categories Mode parameter**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#related-categories-mode). As stated in the docs:

> This parameter is intended for use only when you are using the channel tag within “single entry” pages. Single entry pages are ones that show only a single entry, specified by the ID number or URL Title in the URL.
>
> When enabled, this parameter alters the behavior of the {exp:channel:entries} tag, causing it to ignore the entry ID or URL title found in the URL, and ***instead show a list of entries that are in the same category as the entry specified in the URL. This lets you create a list of entries that are “related” to the primary one specified by the URL.***

---

Your "More Sports" section of the page would look something like:

```
<ul class="post">
{exp:channel:entries related_categories_mode="yes" limit="4"}
    <li>
        <a href="{url_title_path='blog/full-post'}">
            <div class="featured-tab {url_title}"></div>
        </a>
        <a href="{url_title_path='blog/full-post'}"><img src="{blog_slide_image}" alt="placeholder" class="feature-preview-img"></a>
        <p>{exp:eehive_hacksaw chars="250" append="..."}{feature_copy}{/exp:eehive_hacksaw}</p>
    </li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Note: I removed the `dynamic="yes" sort="asc" status="open"` parameters because these are defaults on the channel:entries tag so are a given. You should probably add a channel="" parameter too.

This will return 4 articles in the same categories as the current "detail" article on the page.

---

You Blog Roll code would look something like:

```
<ul class="results-row">
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" disable="member_data|trackbacks" related_categories_mode="yes" limit="4"}
    <li>
        <a href="{url_title_path='blog/full-post'}">
            <div class="featured-tab {url_title}"></div>
            <img src="{blog_slide_image}" alt="placeholder" class="feature-preview-img">
        </a>
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <p>{exp:eehive_hacksaw chars="150" append="..."}{feature_copy}{/exp:eehive_hacksaw}</p>
    </li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: it's doesn't seem to display anything when i add that [link](http://bodyworksforme.com/?/blog/blog-roll/category/energy)